# Angular WebAPI POST service call replaces '+' char in request body

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, urlencode

I am making a POST call from Angular to .Net WebAPI which works on most cases but causing problem when passing a request parameter which contains a '+' sign as a trailing character.
In .Net WebAPI Service which used **Newtonsoft.Json** for serialization, when receives request object that missing '+' at the end of the request.

My Angular Code :

`const body = new HttpParams().set('UserID', 'James').set('Password', 'Bond+');

this.http.post(API_URLS.UserAuthentication, body.toString(),{ headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') }`

Seems to me it's not problem with Angular or .Net , but I may be missing something here.

Comment: try by using `%2B` instead of `+`. the problem most likely lies in the fact that the + is interpreted as a space

Comment: @LucaRegazzi, actually in application password is entered by user of the application, as application developer we don't have control on that.

Comment: try using a string replace, just to see if it solves the problem. If this is the problem there is a more angular way of solving thisby providing a custom HttpParameterCodec to the HttpParams constructor

Comment: @LucaRegazzi, if I replace '%2B' with '+' in client side angular code , then server gets '%2B' not '+'

Comment: @LucaRegazzi, I got your point when I looked into Angular source code of params file (...http/src/params.ts) thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `encodeURIComponent` method to encode the password value. So, you will be setting the password in the `HttpParams` object something like this:

```
const body = new HttpParams().set('UserID', 'James').set('Password', encodeURIComponent('Bond+'));
```

Now, when you get the value of `Password` in the .Net API, it should be something like 'Bond%2B' which you can again decode using `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`